# Experiences with integration testing java web applications, is cucumber viable?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, integration-testing

I know cucumber from the rails community, and it seems to potentially be used in java.

Has anyone actually used it successfully on a project?  Any issues with it?

I am thinking selenium is probably the most stable solution for integration testing a spring app?

With selenium, I guess the best way would be to use the browser add-on correct?  I am looking for a simple and effective solution that isn't time consuming to create/maintain and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's viable, although I used JRuby for Java library integration.

Personally, I'm not a fan. I much prefer [easyb](http://www.easyb.org/), although part of the reason was an easier transition for some devs from Java to something higher-level. I find Cucumber a bit hoop-ful, but YMMV.

We had a few glitches making easyb output play nice with Hudson, but relatively minor.

Comment: Wow! I like that is has a rspec feel to it.  Is this lib widely used or its new/niche?

Comment: @codecompleting It's certainly not new, but I don't have any idea how widely it's used. You could also use RSpec (through JRuby if you prefer). I prefer either over Cucumber, but that's just me.

Comment: Any tutorials for that? So I run rspec via jruby, and then for my steps I just import my java into jruby?  That sounds interesting...

Comment: @codecompleting Tutorials for what, JRuby/Java integration? Only what's on the wiki (and on blogs), although there's a Using JRuby book that discusses Cucumber/etc. (I have the book but haven't read it yet.)